# How to limit search 'text input' results to return only those in selected 'category' filter drop down

Tags: javascript, search, filter, html-table

I have pulled together script from this forum to help me filter search results from quite a complex table. I want users to be able to 1. Select the category and 2. search the table using a text input field.

I have both of these functions working individually, but I would like the search function (text input) to only show results which are filtered by the category type selected. At present, the search function overrides the category input and displays any table rows from ALL table rows, regardless of category.

In the code below for example, I would like to have category set at 'all' and search Taylor, returning 2 results. I would also like to be able to select category 3 and search Taylor and receive only 1 result.

Can anybody help me please?
Thank you!

```
<div class="container">

    <h2>Finder</h2>

     <div class="step1">
        <p>Show category:</p>
     </div>

     <select type="search" class="select-table-filter" data-table="order-table" id="searchInput">
        <option value="">All</option>  
        <option value="1">1</option>  
        <option value="2">2</option>  
        <option value="3">3</option>  
     </select>

<input type="search" class="light-table-filter" data-table="order-table" placeholder="Search ..." />
<table class="order-table" id="myTable">
   <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>Taylor</td>
         <td>Swift</td>
         <td>1234 5678</td>
         <td>taytay@gmail.com</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>John</td>
         <td>Smith</td>
         <td>1234 5678</td>
         <td>johnnyboy@gmail.com</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>Jane</td>
         <td>Doh</td>
         <td>1234 5678</td>
         <td>dohnut@gmail.com</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>Taylor</td>
         <td>Doh</td>
         <td>1234 5678</td>
         <td>td@gmail.com</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my script:

```
(function(document) {
'use strict';

var LightTableFilter = (function(Arr) {

var _input;
var _select;

    /***** FUNCTION FOR SEARCH INPUT *****/
    function _onInputEvent(e) {
        _input = e.target;
        var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
        Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
            Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
                Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);
            });
        });
    }




    /***** INPUT CODE TO SEARCH ONLY FIRST COLUMN *****/
    function _onSelectEvent(e) {
          var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
          txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
          if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }       
      }
    }


    function _filter(row) {

        var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
        row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';

    }


    return {
        init: function() {
            var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('light-table-filter');
            var selects = document.getElementsByClassName('select-table-filter');
            Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
                input.oninput = _onInputEvent;
            });
            Arr.forEach.call(selects, function(select) {
                select.onchange  = _onSelectEvent;
            });
                }
            };
        })(Array.prototype);

        document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
            if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
                LightTableFilter.init();
            }
        });


        })(document);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```js
function _filter(row) {
            var input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
            var category = row.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent;
            var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
            row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : ((filter === '' || category === filter) && 'table-row');
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Waiaan! This is perfect! 

Do you know if there is a way to clear the search 'text input' if a user changes the category mid-search? At the moment you can change the category with text remaining in the search box, and it appears as though it's still filtering using both text input and category, but it is not.

Comment: @Nic in the function _onSelectEvent(e) , you can add a method to clear the 'text input' value

Comment: Thank you - I couldn't figure it out exactly but it sent me in the right direction to apply an onclick="document.getElementById('myID').value = '' " which has worked week enough so far ;)